# Weird listview behavior?

Tags: c#, listview

This issue is driving me crazy..

This code raises index out of range exception for the messagebox:

```
    private void MainTabs_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainTabs.SelectedTab.Name == "ActiveDirectoryTab")
        {
            ADServerSelect.Items[0].Selected = true;
            MessageBox.Show(ADServerSelect.Items[0].Text);
        }
    }
```

But if the messagebox is the result of an event it works just fine:

```
    private void MainTabs_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainTabs.SelectedTab.Name == "ActiveDirectoryTab")
        {
            ADServerSelect.Items[0].Selected = true;
        }
    }

    private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ADServerSelect.Items[0].Text); 
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Can we see a bit more code, how are you binding data, etc?

Comment: Is all of this running in the same thread?

Comment: 1. nothing fancy in data binding.. the items are hard coded
2. All is running on the same thread(UI)

Comment: @Shlomi, Please can we see how you bind your data, and perhaps the XAML too?  Without seeing more of your code, it's not clear why you're getting this error.

Comment: @Matt, What do you mean by binding data? It's just a simple WinForms listview, and I've added the the items(listViewItem) through the VS designer manually. Can you please point me at the relevenat code section you want to see? Thanks

Comment: Sorry! I thought it was WPF listview. Forget I said anything

Answer (score 2):

looks like items added to the listview AFTER MainTabs_Selected event. can you check it?

Comment: This line of code works fine:
ADServerSelect.Items[0].Selected = true; //select listview first item

So I must assume the listview items are added before this event, isn't?